# Show a function is not Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $g : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
>
> $$g(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if ${n \in \mathbb{Q}}$} \\
> -1, & \text{if ${n \in \mathbb{ R\setminus Q}}$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $g$ is not integrable.

**Solution:**

We find the dissection to be
$$D_n=\left(0,\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{n-1}{n},1\right)$$

As both the rationals and irrationals are dense on the real line, we find that
$$m_i=-1$$
$$M_i=1$$

Then finding the lower and upper sums as

$$\underline{s}(D)=\sum^n_{i=1}m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
$$\bar{s}(D)=\sum^n_{i=1}M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

respectively,

$$\underline{s}(D)=-1\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\bar{s}(D)=1\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{n}$$

finally

$$\underline{s}(D)=-\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\bar{s}(D)=\frac{1}{n}$$

As $n\to\infty$, $\ \underline{s}(D)\to0$ and $\bar{s}(D)\to0.$

This is incorrect as $\bar{s}(D)-\underline{s}(D)<\varepsilon,$ which meets Riemanns criteria, and the function is integrable.

**Where have I gone wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = 1$ and not $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you. Very obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

The lower sum is $-1$ and the upper sum is $1$, because
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1n=1$$

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
\underset{\raise0.3em\hbox{$\smash{\scriptscriptstyle-}$}}{s} (D) =  - 1\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}
{n}}  =  - 1\left( {n\frac{1}
{n}} \right) =  - 1
$$
while
$$
\bar s(D) = 1\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}
{n}}  = 1\left( {n\frac{1}
{n}} \right) = 1
$$
Therefore
$$
\bar s(D) - \underset{\raise0.3em\hbox{$\smash{\scriptscriptstyle-}$}}{s} (D) = 2\;\;\;\forall n\in \mathbb N
$$
and this tell you that the function is not Riemann integrable

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the result, a function $g:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of point of discontinuities of $g$ has the measure zero. Now since in the your question, the point of discontinuities has measure 1, therefore it is not integrable.